# How can I simulate a phone call from "Unavailable" in the android studio device emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, broadcastreceiver

I'm making an app using Broadcast Receiver and I want my phone to be able to handle calls from "Unavailable". I don't want to wait until I get a call from "Unavailable" before being able to do a test. How can I simulate a call from "Unavailable" in an android studio emulator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

connect to your PC using telnet on the port of your emulator, e.g.

```
telnet localhost 5554
```

and use the gsm call command with a number of # instead of digits

```
gsm call #
```

and you'll receive your unknown call on the emulator's phone.